# How to create a numpy array with a start and stop value with a percentage increment?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to created an array based on a start, stop and step(in %). So for eg.

```
start = 10
stop = 20
step = 2 # equals 2%
```

Needs to create the following array:

```
[10.        , 10.2       , 10.404     , 10.61208   , 10.8243216 ,
 11.04080803, 11.26162419, 11.48685668, 11.71659381, 11.95092569,
 12.1899442 , 12.43374308, 12.68241795, 12.9360663 , 13.19478763,
 13.45868338, 13.72785705, 14.00241419, 14.28246248, 14.56811173,
 14.85947396, 15.15666344, 15.45979671, 15.76899264, 16.08437249,
 16.40605994, 16.73418114, 17.06886477, 17.41024206, 17.7584469 ,
 18.11361584, 18.47588816, 18.84540592, 19.22231404, 19.60676032,
 19.99889553, 20.39887344]
```

The 'stop' value (20) may be exceeded by one entry.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the size of the array:

```
import math, numpy as np
incr = 1 + step / 100
size = math.ceil(math.log(stop / start, incr)) + 1
```

Create an empty array of the required size:

```
arr = np.empty(size + 1)
```

Initialize it with the increment:

```
arr[:] = incr
```

Set the first value to `start`:

```
arr[0] = start
```

Calculate the cumulative product:

```
arr.cumprod()
```